# determining terminal's ability to format output?

Tags: bash, terminfo

Hullo - If I want to determine the # of colours a terminal can display I simply read the output of

```
 tput colors
```

... however I cannot figure out how to determine if the terminal I'm writing to can support other formatting requests such as bold, underline, reverse-video, blink (yuck!).

I see how to set output via tput, but not determine if the capability exists before attempting.

Should I simply assume the capability exists in all terminals ?

Comment: Note that this won't tell you if the terminal emulator will support the attribute, only that a terminfo entry exists for the attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `infocmp` for this, and `grep` on the capability you are looking for. If a result is found, then the capability is supported:

```
infocmp | grep bold
    bel=^G, bold=\E[1m, clear=\E[H\E[2J, cr=^M,
```

In order to get the names of the different capabilities check out [the Linux man pages for terminfo](http://linux.die.net/man/5/terminfo), or [this one](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?terminfo+5) for a tabular layout of names.

Answer (score 2):

There may be an easier way, but you can query the terminfo database by running

```
infocmp $TERM
```

to see the full entry for the current terminal (replace `$TERM` with the name of any supported terminal type). You'll probably want to read the man page to figure out how to create output most easily parsed for your given need.

Answer (score 1):

If you try a `tput` command with an undefined attribute it will return a non-zero exit code. You can redirect the normal output, if any, to avoid having it take effect.

```
for attr in bold rev smul blink sshm
do
    if ! tput "$attr" > /dev/null
    then
        echo "Attribute $attr is undefined"
    fi
done
```

Otherwise, if you `grep` the output of `infocmp`, use the `-1` (that's a one) option to output the attributes one per line.

```
infocmp -1 | grep smul
```